# issue with to_iso_string() in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, boost

We have wrapper.cpp file Using which, we are creating libwrapper.so and we are linking this library with set of c files to create an executable (using gcc compiler). Till now I haven't faced any problem even though I used boost library in wrapper.cpp.

But Now below code in wrapper.cpp is creating problem.

```
void callbackTimeZoneChanged(short unsigned int eventid, void *arg)
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    using namespace boost::local_time;

    time_zone_ptr zone(new posix_time_zone(*(char**)arg));

    const int currentYear  = second_clock::local_time().date().year();
    const string hasDST    = zone->has_dst() ? "true" : "false";
    const string startTime = to_iso_string(zone >dst_local_start_time(currentYear));
    const string endTime   = to_iso_string(zone->dst_local_end_time(currentYear));
}
```

I am able to compile wrapper.cpp file and able to create libwrapper.so but when I tried to create executable using gcc, I am getting the following error.

```
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/kadina/build/platform/component/platform/stb/TR069':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

if I remove the lines which contain to_iso_string(), this is working fine and I am able to create executable file.
Can any one please help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: This does not look like related to your code, but to building the toolchain. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: if I remove the lines which contain to_iso_string(), this is working fine and I am able to create executable file.

Comment: What is the command you are using to compile your code? Boost date_time requires precompilation and must be linked with your executable.

Comment: I am using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc to create executable.